# django messages wont show up in template

Tags: python, django, authentication, message

Okey this has been asked aloooot but no answer has helped, tried tutorials and asked my student collegues for help but no one can answer why. They have looked and says it looks fine, that it could be something wrong with my django itself.
I'm trying to just show a successful logged in message on my django app. I can't make it work.
Please bare with me, my first django project and im a student that suffers real bad from imposter syndrome, play nice :)

My folder setup

- home <--app
- projectfolder
- media
- static with images and css folder
- users <-- app

So to start off i use djangos built in auth system. Works great on the site.
Using djangos own form for login and logout.
Whats really weird is that the div dosent even show up when i render the page and check inspect, nothing in console either.

```
views.py in users

from django.contrib import messages
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate, login, logout
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect

def login_user(request):
    """ Login form and messages """
    if request.method == "POST":
        username = request.POST['username']
        password = request.POST['password']
        user = authenticate(request, username=username, password=password)
        if user is not None:
            login(request, user)
            messages.success(request, "You have been successfully logged in.")
            return redirect('home')
        else:
            messages.error(request, "There was an error during login.")
            return redirect('login')
    else:
        return render(request, 'register/login.html')
```

```
settings.py

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'cloudinary_storage',
    'cloudinary',
    'home',
    'users',
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [TEMPLATES_DIR],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = '/'
LOGOUT_REDIRECT_URL = '/'
```

urls.py in user

```
from django.urls import path
from .views import UserRegister, ProfileEdit
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('register/', UserRegister.as_view(), name='register'),
    path('profile_edit/', ProfileEdit.as_view(), name='profile_edit'),
    path('login/', views.login_user, name='login'),

]
```

base.html where i try to render the message

```
<!-- Alert container when logged in -->
  {% if messages %}
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-8 offset-md-2">
        {% for message in messages %}
        <div class="alert alert-{{ message.tags }} alert-dismissible fade show" role="alert">
          {{ message }}
          <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close"></button>
        </div>
        {% endfor %}
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  {% endif %}
```

So i have tried copying Codemy's django blog tutorial with no luck, used my schools approach didnt work, copied alot of examples from other stackoverflow posts but no luck.

Expect a successful message to be shown to the user.

```
Edit:
My login.html

    {% extends 'base.html' %}
    {% load static %}
    
    {% block title %} Login {% endblock %}
    
    {% block content %}
    <!-- Login form -->
    <div class="col text-center mt-4">
        <h1> Login</h1>
        <br>
        <div class="form-group">
            <form action="{%url 'login' %}" method="POST">
                {% csrf_token %}
                <input type="text" name="username" class="form-control" placeholder="Username">
                <br>
                <input type="password" name="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Password">
                <br>
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-lime mb-4 mt-4">Sign in</button>
            </form>
        </div>
        <!-- Register buttons -->
        <div class="text-center">
            <p>Not a member? <a href="{% url 'register' %}">Register</a></p>
        </div>
    </div>
    {% endblock %}

my base.html
{% load static %}
{% load cloudinary %}
<head>
code...
</head>
<body>
<navbar>
</navbar>
<!-- Alert container when logged in -->
{% if messages %}
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-8 offset-md-2">
        {% for message in messages %}
        {% if message.tags == 'error' %}
            <div class="alert alert-danger alert-dismissible 
fade show" role="alert">
        {% else %}
            <div class="alert alert-{{ message.tags }} alert- 
dismissible fade show" role="alert">
        {% endif %}
        {{ message }}
        <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs- 
dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close"></button>
        </div>
        {% endfor %}
    </div>
    </div>
</div>
{% endif %}
{% block content %}
<!-- Content goes here -->
{% endblock content %}
<footer>
</footer>
```

Okey so add more stuff here to see if someone can spot the error.

This is my projects urls.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', include('home.urls')),
    path('users/', include('django.contrib.auth.urls')),
    path('users/', include('users.urls')),
]
```

My home apps urls.py

from .views import (
Index, PostView, PostDetailView,
PostCreateView, PostUpdateView,
PostDeleteView, LikeView,
SearchResultsView
)
from .import views

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('', Index.as_view(), name='home'),
    path('posts', PostView.as_view(), name="posts"),
    path('posts/<int:pk>', PostDetailView.as_view(), 
name='post_detail'),
    path('create', PostCreateView.as_view(), name='post_create'),
    path('edit/<int:pk>', PostUpdateView.as_view(), 
name='post_edit'),
    path('home/<int:pk>/delete', PostDeleteView.as_view(), 
name='post_delete'),
    path('postlike/<int:pk>', LikeView, name='post_like'),
    path("search", SearchResultsView.as_view(), 
name="search_results"),

]
```

Comment: is your error message showing correctly in login.html ? and I don't see 'home' in your urls.py nor view or html code for your home ? Have your correctly load base.html in your home template ?

Comment: I have my url to ”home” in my home app. Could that be an issue? I am trying to display the message in my base.html. Is i better to display it om my ”home”(index.html)? Does it all make sence?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, editing my answer with a solution to your issue after repo sharing.

The problem was at your root `urls.py` setup [order](https://github.com/andreas-ka/show-your-keyboard/blob/main/ShowYourKeyboard/urls.py#L7-L8):

```py
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', include('home.urls')),
    path('users/', include('users.urls')),
    path('users/', include('django.contrib.auth.urls')),
]
```

`django.contrib.auth.urls` has a login view, so yours was not being called. Thus, not attaching messages to the request. So just move `include('users.urls')` up and now when the request URL is `/users/login` then the first match will be the view inside `users` app.

Also, adjust your view accordingly, the subfolder that holds your templates is called [`resgistration`](https://github.com/andreas-ka/show-your-keyboard/tree/main/users/templates/registration) not [`register`](https://github.com/andreas-ka/show-your-keyboard/blob/main/users/views.py#L27). And, you can remove the [redirection](https://github.com/andreas-ka/show-your-keyboard/blob/main/users/views.py#L24), its just redundant.

```
def login_user(request):
    """Login form and messages"""
    if request.method == "POST":
        username = request.POST["username"]
        password = request.POST["password"]
        user = authenticate(request, username=username, password=password)
        if user is not None:
            login(request, user)
            messages.success(request, "You have been successfully logged in.")
            return redirect('home')
        else:
            messages.error(request, "There was an error during login.")

    return render(request, "registration/login.html")
```

Lastly, to display the message, add the previous answer code to `base.html` [between `</nav>` and `{% block content %}`](https://github.com/andreas-ka/show-your-keyboard/blob/main/templates/base.html#L75-L76) and remove our current message block at [`login.html`](https://github.com/andreas-ka/show-your-keyboard/blob/main/users/templates/registration/login.html#L8-L18) .:

```
{% if messages %}
<div class="container">
   <div class="row">
   <div class="col-md-8 offset-md-2">
         {% for message in messages %}
         {% if message.tags == 'error' %}
            <div class="alert alert-danger alert-dismissible fade show" role="alert">
         {% else %}
            <div class="alert alert-{{ message.tags }} alert-dismissible fade show" role="alert">
         {% endif %}
         {{ message }}
         <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close"></button>
         </div>
         {% endfor %}
   </div>
   </div>
</div>
{% endif %}
```

#### Further Notes

[`ListView`](https://github.com/andreas-ka/show-your-keyboard/blob/main/home/views.py#L20) is not based on `FormView` so adding a `success_message` to it [will not work](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/contrib/messages/#adding-messages-in-class-based-views).

By adding the message to `base.html` you have a break in styling. Although I believe you can easily fix that with [`z-index`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/z-index).

Comment: I've (completely coincidentally) been working on something rather similar. I didn't use a conditional. I used settings.py `MESSAGE_TAGS={ ERROR: "danger error"}`. Note, in a template you can do `{{message.level_tag.split|first}}` if you don't want a class "error" as well as xxx-danger

Comment: @Niko i really appreciate your effort and time but i didn't help. I will edit my question with how my login.html looks like and a part of the base.html. Everything from the base renders fine on all pages. In my case im trying to render the message on base.html right under the navbar, both that and rendering at index.html dont work. Tried even putting it the footer. with just a for loop to get something but no luck

Comment: So when you successfully login the message shows up at `home.html`? Also, I noticed that you are not closing your `<body />` tag at `base.html`.

Comment: Yeah i just forgot to copy the closing tag. The message dont show on either index.html, base.html or login.html. Got the code snippet for displaying the message you wrote on all 3 pages. ☹️

Comment: Could you check if you `messages` are being attached to the `request` object? It is the last code block in this [`documentation`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/contrib/messages/#displaying-messages) example. Preferably from `login` view to `home` (check at home).

Comment: @Niko so sorry, i dont really follow, do you mean get_message() ? if so how do i check?

Comment: Yes, `get_messages` will retrieve the storage that contains your messages. Just place that block inside your `home` view (aside the import)  and replace `do_something_with_the_message` for `print`. Then, login and output should be `"You have been successfully logged in."` (on your terminal ofc)

Comment: @Niko from django.contrib import messages
from django.contrib.messages import get_messages
    

class Index(ListView):
    """View for the index or home page"""
    template_name = 'home/index.html'
    model = Post
    context_object_name = 'post'
    
    def getMessages(request):
        storage = get_messages(request)
        for message in storage:
            print(message) sry but nothing comes up in the terminal

Comment: [17/Jun/2023 20:34:41] "GET /users/login/ HTTP/1.1" 200 6469
[17/Jun/2023 20:34:46] "POST /users/login/ HTTP/1.1" 302 0
[17/Jun/2023 20:34:48] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 15230

Comment: Would it be easier if i gave you my github repo? appreciate your time!

Comment: Sorry for the late response. Sure, this way I can test your code directly. Also, remember to not post code on comment, append them to your question :)

Comment: @Niko yeah no worries, i have a tutor from school looking at it but it dosent look good :D here is my repo https://github.com/andreas-ka/show-your-keyboard if you want to look :D

Comment: @Niko Thank you so much, it worked! That makes me so happy. Appreciate your time for this, so grateful!